# Merge consecutive cells in excel sheet having same values using Apache POI in JAVA

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hi I created a excell sheet using Apache poi library. I want to merge consecutive cells having same value. I am using below provided logic. But it's not working properly.i need to merge columns like below image provided.
[image]

```
System.out.println("Total rows: " + pageListAcrToDept.size());
            int commonval = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < 13; column++) {
                for (int rowno = 8; rowno < pageListAcrToDept.size() + 8; rowno++) {
                    for (int j = rowno + 1; j < pageListAcrToDept.size() + 8; j++) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   " + rowno + " " + j);
                            if (sheet.getRow(rowno).getCell(column).toString().trim()
                                    .equals(sheet.getRow(j).getCell(column).toString().trim())) {
                                System.out.println(sheet.getRow(rowno).getCell(column).toString() + "\n\n i "
                                        + rowno + " j " + j + " column no " + column);
                                commonval = j;
                            } else {
                                if (commonval != 0) {
                                    CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(rowno, commonval,
                                            column, column);
                                    sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);
                                    commonval = 0;
                                }
                                rowno = j;
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Exception at i: " + rowno + " j:" + j + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is consecutive for you? each cell in a row and then next row, or each cell in A then B and so on?

Comment: Try to compare cell actual values instead of toString() method return value

Comment: consecutive rows value for each columns(Like the image provided)

Comment: try to include what is not working with your code, what is it giving as output, so we can help with finding the bug